# Won't display data in run, or won't display data in debug. 

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

This is the edit to my question. There is quite a bit of code here, but the problem area is below the second set of three line comments. I stuck the rest in just in case I'm completely wrong about where the problem is. With the "if" statement I can display fine in a run, but not in debug. If I get rid of the conditional it runs fine in debug, but not in a regular run. These errors only occur on the first run of the quiz. In either mode it runs fine  fi I take a second quiz. Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks...

```
    // ** this function is called from another component that passes in the array of qnums 
    // ** and  then function clears data from previous quizzes. Component starts in the 
    // ** "loadingState **//    
        public function startQuiz(qNums:Array):void
        {
            quizNumbers = qNums;
            // ** deleted the reset functions for readability ** //
            showQuestion();
        }

    // ** calls the questions from sql  ** //
        protected function showQuestion():void{
            getQuestionByNumberResult.token = quizService.getQuestionByNumber(quizNumbers[i]);
        }

    // ** result handler from the sql call  and randomizes answers and feedbacks ** //      
        protected function getQuestionByNumberResult_resultHandler(event:ResultEvent):void
        {
        // ** deleted the logic that builds the arrays and randomizes them ** //
            ranAnswerArray = Randomizer.qsAndFbcks(answersArray, tempArray);
            ranFeebbackArray = Randomizer.qsAndFbcks(feedbackArray, tempArray);


        // ** This seems to be where the problem is. With the "if" statement it runs fine in a ** //
        // ** regular run, but doesn't display the first question in debug mode. Without the "if" and I just ** //                  // ** call  the showTheQuestion() function it is the problem is reversed ; it runs fine in debug, ** //
        // ** but doesn't show the first question in a regular run. ** //


            if (currentState != "quizingState"){
            currentState="quizingState";
            addEventListener(StateChangeEvent.CURRENT_STATE_CHANGE, quizStateChange);}
            else{ showTheQuestion();}

            //showTheQuestion();            
        }
        // ** function called from state change listener ** //
        protected function quizStateChange(event:StateChangeEvent):void
        {
            showTheQuestion();
        }
        // ** this function tells the visual components what to display ** //
        protected function showTheQuestion():void{
            // ** deleted logic that says how many radios and labels should be visible ** //
            questionText.text = data.question_txt;
            zanswer01.text = ranAnswerArray[0];
            zanswer02.text = ranAnswerArray[1];
            zanswer03.text = ranAnswerArray[2];
            zanswer04.text = ranAnswerArray[3];
        }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>


<s:states>
    <s:State name="quizingState"/>
    <s:State name="loadingState"/>
    <s:State name="finishedState"/>
</s:states>

// ** deleted the declarations block for readability. I left the display components just in case ** //
// ** something seemed wrong with them. ** //   

    <s:Label id="questionText" includeIn="quizingState" x="42" y="54" width="699" height="138" color="#5BAAFB"
             fontFamily="Arial" fontSize="22" fontWeight="normal"
             text=""/>
    <s:Form includeIn="quizingState" x="48" y="167" height="219">
        <s:HGroup id="zhGroup01" verticalAlign="baseline">
            <s:RadioButton groupName="selectedAnswer" value="0"/>
            <s:Label id="zanswer01" text="" verticalAlign="middle"/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="zhGroup02" verticalAlign="baseline">
            <s:RadioButton groupName="selectedAnswer" value="1"/>
            <s:Label id="zanswer02" text=""/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="zhGroup03" verticalAlign="baseline">
            <s:RadioButton id="zradio3" groupName="selectedAnswer" value="2"/>
            <s:Label id="zanswer03" text=""/>
        </s:HGroup>
        <s:HGroup id="zhGroup04" verticalAlign="baseline">
            <s:RadioButton id="zradio4" groupName="selectedAnswer" value="3"/>
            <s:Label id="zanswer04" text=""/>
        </s:HGroup>     
    </s:Form>
```

Comment: You have a lot of code here, but it's still just a single snippet of the app.  It makes it hard to tell what is going on.  You should consider minimizing code down to just enough lines to demonstrate the problem.  You should also consider showing the full error / stack trace.  Then highlight the line number which the error actually occurs on.

Comment: if (ranAnswerArray.length == 4) is where it dies. I'm guessing it dies because this code:  currentState="quizingState";
            showTheQuestion();

Comment: is not in the right order? Thanks for the fast responce and I will remember that in the future. I just notice that sometimes people leave out code that is a problem so I guess I err'd on the side of too much instead of too little. I will minimize in the future.

Comment: The balance between code and no code is tough to figure out.  Ideally it should be enough to demonstrate the problem; and nothing more.  Remember that changing the state takes time.  Do you want to execute the "showTheQuestion" method after the state change?  You can listen to the currentStateChange event.  Or if you want to execute the method while the state change is taking place, then leave the code as is.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run `showTheQuestion()` right after a state change.  Your components in the state haven't had time to initialize just yet.  I would argue that you don't need that function since the state is the one that show "show the question".

If you really need it, you should add it to a creation complete event on one of the state components, or maybe the `enterState` event on the state itself.

Comment: +1 for saying that it sounds like the state should already know how to show the question.  However, assuming it doesn't [for whatever reason] wouldn't the currentStateChanged event be a better choice than creationComplete()?   http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#event:currentStateChange

Comment: @Flextras, I gave creationComplete as a choice because I don't know which component he's trying to reference and how long it takes to initialize.  There's no guarantee that currentStateChanged event will have all UIComponents initialized.

Comment: I went with StateChangeEvent, it made it all work for me. I am surprised that it runs that much slower in debug than in a normal run. Thanks for a the helpful responses. As a side note, about the state knowing how to display the question, do you think it's better to do that in the MXML, rather than in the actionscript? I use the showQuestion to tell the component how to display and it decides how many answers to show (some have 3, others have 2). If it's not too much trouble could you elaborate? Either way, thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: Funny thing, now it displays with no error in a regular run, but it doesn't display the first question in debug mode. It doesn't throw an error at me, but different behavior again. Any idea why I have this funny behavior?

Comment: Probably because you aren't using [states properly](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fb4.html).

Comment: @J_A_X, I looked at the documentation you linked to and there is nothing glaring at me as a mistake. It is a custom component with 3 states. Loading(while waiting for the sql result), quizzing, and finished(shows result of quiz). Does this sound wrong? I'm rather new to this, but I would like to do it right. Obviously I'm not. Thanks.

Comment: @J_A_X I edited my question and reposted  my code if you can look at it, that would be great. Thanks.

Comment: So, the function only sets the questions' text?  Why not create an ArrayCollection and bind them automatically?  The other way would be to only set visibility to false when not in the questions state and set them manually in your result handler function.

Comment: @J_A_X Thanks, the arrayCollection worked out all the issues.